# Way to set cookie variable on remote site.

Tags: php, parsing, session

I need to query a remote website that sets a custom session ID for each visit. I need to obtain that session ID and store it in a variable. I need to do this in PHP. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Perform an HTTP request to that site and extract the session id value from `set-cookie` header

Answer (score 0):

The below code does exactly as requested:

```
    <?php
    $ch = curl_init('http://example.com');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    // get headers too with this line
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    // get cookie
    preg_match('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $result, $m);

    parse_str($m[1], $cookies);
    var_dump($cookies);
    ?>
```